# How to combine tabular form and text area in one page?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page, containing tabular data(region type SQL Query (updateable report)). It only updates existing rows using Submit. The wizard created ApplyMRU process. It works fine. But now I would like to place a text area in the same page, which will be bound to different table and will get updated once the same Submit button is pressed. How can I accomplish it?

I've created item for text area, but not sure what type of source I should set. Database column doesn't let me specify table. Also I guess I need a second after submit process, but not sure which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your existing ApplyMRU infrastructure for the tabular form, and just define a second PL/SQL process that executes during page submit that will do whatever it is you want with your text area, eg:

```
insert into notes (id, text) values (:P1_ID, :P1_TEXT_AREA);
```

Take note of the order of the processes, as you may want to execute one before the other.